# MYSQL slow duration or fetch time depending on "distinct" command

Tags: mysql, optimization, distinct, fetch, duration

I have a pretty small, simple MYSQL table for holding precalculated financial data.  The table looks like:
refDate | instrtument | rate|startDate |maturityDate|carry1|carry2|carry3

with 3 indices defined as:

unique unique_ID(refDate,instrument)

refDate (refDate)

instrument (instrument)

rows right now is about 10 million, though for each refDate, there are only about 5000 distinct instruments right now

I have a query that self joins on this table to generate an output like:
refDate|rate instrument=X | rate instrument = Y| rate instrument=Z|....

basically returning time series data which I can then do my own analytics in.

Here is the problem: my original query looked like:

```
Select distinct AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,AUDSpot1yFq.rate as 'AUDSpot1yFq',
AUD1y1yFq.rate as AUD1y1yFq
from audratedb AUDSpot1yFq inner join audratedb AUD1y1yFq on
AUDSpot1yFq.refDate=AUD1y1yFq.refDate 
where AUDSpot1yFq.instrument = 'AUDSpot1yFq' and 
AUD1y1yFq.instrument = 'AUD1y1yFq' 
order by AUDSpot1yFq.refDate
```

Note, in this particular query for timing below, I was actually getting 10 different instruments, which means the query was much longer but followed this same pattern of naming, inner joins, and where statements.

This was slow, in workbench I time it as 7-8 second duration (but near 0 fetch time, as I have workbench on the machine running the server).   When I stripped the distinct, the duration drops to 0.25-0.5 seconds (far more manageable) and when I stripped the "order by" it got even faster (<0.1 seconds, at which point I don't care).  But my Fetchtime exploded to ~7 seconds.  So in total, I gain nothing but it has all become a Fetch time issue.  When I run this query from the python scripts that will be doing the lifting and work, I get roughly the same timing whether I include distinct or not.

when I run an explain on my cut down query (which has the horrid fetch time) I get:

```
1   SIMPLE  AUDSpot1yFq     ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    instrument  39  const   1432    100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD1y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD2y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD3y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD4y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD5y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD6y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD7y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD8y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  AUD9y1yFq       ref unique_ID,refDate,instrument    unique_ID   42  historicalratesdb.AUDSpot1yFq.refDate,const 1   100.00  Using where
```

I now realize distinct is not required, and order by is something I can throw out and sort in pandas when I get the output to a dataframe.  That is great.  But I don't know how to get the Fetch time down.  I'm not going to win any competency competitions on this website, but I have searched as much as I can and can't find a solution for this issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

~cocoa

Comment: Hi community, I'm not sure why this solution worked (considering I didn't THINK I changed the query in a very meaningful way in regards to fetch time) but it seems my time collapses to basically as fast as I could hope after I changed the innodb_buffer_pool_size (from 1G to 2G). 

I'd like to alter the request, can anyone explain this behavior changing so drastically when you remove the "distinct" from the select statement?  Does the data become that much harder to stitch together? And would it perform better if I instead had used subselect queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I had to simplify the table aliases in order to read it:)

```
Select  distinct
           s.refDate,
           s.rate as AUDSpot1yFq,
           y.rate as AUD1y1yFq
    from  audratedb AS s
    join  audratedb AS y  on s.refDate = y.refDate
    where  s.instrument = 'AUDSpot1yFq'
      and  y.instrument = 'AUD1y1yFq'
    order by  s.refDate
```

Index needed:

```
INDEX(instrument, refDate)  -- To filter and sort, or
INDEX(instrument, refDate, rate)  -- to also "cover" the query.
```

That *assumes* the query is not more complex than you said.  I see that the `EXPLAIN` already has many more tables.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE audratedb` and the entire `SELECT`.

Back to your questions...

`DISTINCT` is done one of two ways:  (1) sort the table, then dedup, or (2) dedup in a hash in memory.  Keep in mind that you are dedupping all 3 columns (refDate, s.rate, y.rate).

`ORDER BY` is a sort after gathering all the data.  However, with the suggested index (*not* the indexes you had), the sort is not needed, since the index will get the rows in the desired order.

But...  Having *both* `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` may confuse the Optimizer to the point where it does something 'dumb'.

You say that `(refDate,instrument)` is `UNIQUE`, but you do not mention a `PRIMARY KEY`, nor have you mentioned which Engine you are using.  If you are using InnoDB, then `PRIMARY KEY(instrument, refDate)`, *in that order*, would further speed things up, and avoid the need for any new index.

Furthermore, it is redundant to have `(a,b)` and also `(a)`.  That is, your current schema does not need `INDEX(refDate)`, but by changing the PK, you would not need `INDEX(instrument)`, instead.

Bottom line:  Only

```
PRIMARY KEY(instrument, refDate),
INDEX(refDate)
```

and no other indexes (unless you can show some query that needs it).

More on the `EXPLAIN`.  Notice how the `Rows` column says 1432, 1, 1, ...  That means that it scanned an estimated 1432 rows of the first table.  This is probably far more than necessary because of lack of a proper index.  Then it needed to look at only 1 row in each of the other tables.  (Can't get better than that.)

How many rows in the `SELECT` *without* the `DISTINCT` or `ORDER BY`?  That tells you how much work was needed *after* doing the fetching and `JOINing`.  I suspect it is only a few.  A "few" is really cheap for `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`; hence I think you were barking up the wrong tree.  Even 1432 rows would be very fast to process.

As for the buffer_pool...  How big is the table?  Do `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.  I suspect the table is more than 1GB, hence it cannot fit in the buffer_pool.  Hence raising that cache size would let the query run in RAM, not hitting the disk (at least after it gets cached).  Keep in mind that running a query on a cold cache will have lots of I/O.  As the cache warms up, queries will run faster.  But if the cache is too small, you will continue to need I/O.  I/O is the slowest part of the processing.

I hope you have at least 6GB of RAM; otherwise, 2G could be dangerously large.  Swapping is really bad for performance.

Comment: Rick, thanks for all the help.  marked you as having answered the question because basically you have taught me more than enough to sort through it.  Seems my table.  I now understand from your answer what extra data I should show (the table, for example, has about 10 mio rows in it, and the return structure has 1432 rows).   Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't mention existing indexes, or show the output from an `EXPLAIN` for any of the queries.

The quick answer to improve performance is to add an index:

```
   ... ON audratedb (instrument,refdate,rate)
```

To answer why we'd want to add that index, we'd need to understand how MySQL processes SQL statements, what operations are possible, and which are required. To see how MySQL is actually processing your statement, you need to use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan.

Comment: added an explain statement to the above and made more obvious my indices I have on the table.  To be specific, there are 3 indicies, refDate, instrument, and a unique index (refDate,instrument)